# Firestore rules unable to check if a reference exists

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here are my firestore rules:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /customers/{customerId} {
        allow write: if  exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.referred_by));
        allow read: if true;
    }
}
```

The following data does not pass this rule(I was able to create the data from client app by removing the `exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.referred_by)`):

[image]

So how do we deal with the reference field so that I can validate whether this reference exists already or not?

**EDIT:**

The type of the referred_by field is reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that its a limitation of firestore at this stage. We are not able to validate whether a reference exists or not.

I further did some digging using the rules playground. The `request.resource.data.referred_by` has a `path` child. So I used `$(request.resource.data.referred_by.path)`. Still that did not work because the `$(request.resource.data.referred_by.path)` resolves to `customers%2FB85CSuRJQZWUKt2jgxOy` (url-encoded).

[image]
I don't know of a way to url decode this in firestore rules.
So at this time I am changing my data models to use referred_by as a 'string' instead of a reference.

I hope this thing is resolved in future by firestore team.